# Не открывается сайт с www

Tags: apache, nginx

Имеется nginx frontend

```
server{
    listen   80;
    server_name  test3.iandreev.com;
    rewrite ^(.+)$ https://test3.iandreev.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  www.test3.iandreev.com;
    rewrite ^(.+)$ https://www.test3.iandreev.com$1 permanent;
}

upstream backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  test3.iandreev.com www.test3.iandreev.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test3.iandreev.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/test3.iandreev.error.log;


    ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/web-fullchain1.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/web1.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|swf|js)$ {
        root /home/site/adminunix.ru/static/;
    }
}
```

Имеется Apache24 принимает http запрос и возвращает nginx. SSL (https) занимается только nginx как frontend.
Вопрос в том что если в браузере набрать test3.iandreev.com то браузер правильно преобразовывает на https://test3.iandreev.com и сайт открывается. A если набрать www.test3.iandreev.com то результат такой Не удается получить доступ к сайту Не удалось найти IP-адрес сервера www.test3.iandreev.com. Скажите пожалуйста где ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в dns resolver pfsense.